# I need to get data about tulip price between 1936-1937

Tags: finance, data, market-data

I need to daily data for Tulip Price between 1936-1937. How can I find? Please help.

Comment: No idea how reliable this is.  I found it a while back: https://sites.google.com/site/davesmant/monetary-economics/famous-first-bubbles/tulipmania

Comment: I think you're out by about 300 years... I think you mean 1636-1637.